# Separating a text document by specific lines of text using python

Tags: python

I'm writing a python function to take a chunk of text, parsed from a text file using `f.readlines` and split this chunk of text into a list. The text contains dividers and I want to split this text specifically at these locations. Below is an example of the text file in question.

```
@model:2.4.0=Skeleton "Skeleton"
@compartments
 Cell=1.0 "Cell"
@species
 Cell:[A]=100.0 "A"
 Cell:[B]=1.0 "B"
 Cell:[C]=0.0 "C"
 Cell:[D]=0.0 "D"
@parameters
kcat=4000
km = 146
v2_k = 88
@reactions
@r=v1 "v1"
 A -> C : B
 Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A) 
@r=v2 "v2"
 C -> C+D
 Cell * v2_k * C
```

My desired output is to have a python dictionary that has the name of the dividers as keys and all the content between that divider and the next as values. For example, the first element of the `sections` dictionary should be:

```
sections['@model']=:2.4.0=Skeleton "Skeleton"
```

**Current Code**

```
def split_sections(SBshorthand_file):
    '''
    Takes a SBshorthand file and returns a dictionary of each of the sections. 
    Keys of the dictionary are the dividers.
    Values of dictionary are the content between dividers. 
    '''
    SBfile=parse_SBshorthand_read(SBshorthand_file) #simple parsing function. uses f.read()
    dividers=["@model", "@units", "@compartments", "@species", "@parameters", "@rules", "@reactions", "@events"]
    sections={}
    for i in  dividers:
        pattern=re.compile(i)
        if re.findall(pattern,SBfile) == []:
            pass
#            print 'Section \'{}\' not present in {}'.format(i,SBshorthand_file)
        else:
            SBfile2=re.sub(pattern,'\n'+i,SBfile)
            print SBfile2
```

This however does not do what I want. Would anybody have any ideas how to fix my code? Thanks

-----------------Edit--------------------

Please note that the section '@reactions' contains a number of 'reactions' all of which start with @r, but they all need to be grouped under the reactions key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

x="""@model:2.4.0=Skeleton "Skeleton"
@compartments
Cell=1.0 "Cell"
@species
Cell:[A]=100.0 "A"
Cell:[B]=1.0 "B"
Cell:[C]=0.0 "C"
Cell:[D]=0.0 "D"
@parameters
kcat=4000
km = 146
v2_k = 88
@reactions
@r=v1 "v1"
A -> C : B
Cell * kcat * B * A / (km + A)
@r=v2 "v2"
C -> C+D
Cell * v2_k * C"""


print dict(re.findall(r"(?:^|(?<=\n))(@\w+)([\s\S]*?)(?=\n@(?!r\b)\w+|$)",x))
```

You can directly use `re.findall` and get what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally edited your post instead of the question and it wont let me change it back.  Your code works but would you happen to know to exclude the '@r' tag (as I've explained in the edit). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use capture groups as follows:

```
re.findall(r"(?s)(@.*?)[\s:]\s+(.*?)(?=[@$])");
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV8qY3/1)

```
where capture group1 matches the key
capture group2 matches the value
```